# PHP gettext in echo statement?

Tags: php, gettext

I have this line:

```
echo "<li><a href='test'><span class='icon-plus'></span> Test</a></li>";
```

I'm trying to use `gettext` support, but the only way I can get it to work is by breaking this down..

```
echo "<li><a href='test'><span class='icon-plus'></span>"; echo _('Test'); echo "</a></li>";
```

Is there any way to include `_('Test')` which out having to break out and echo it individually ?

Thanks

Comment: `echo "<li><a href='test'><span class='icon-plus'></span>" .  _('Test') . "</a></li>";`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is  basic string concatenation in php

```
 echo "<li><a href='test'><span class='icon-plus'></span>"._('Test')."</a></li>";
```

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about this.. my bad !